# Microsoft Bot Framework - Bot returns specific words when not asked to

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I've been experimenting a bit with a very weird bug. I found out that on some words, it just returns the message back. So this is the code of a bot that's currently running on Slack:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SharpBot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody] Message message)
        {
                if (message.Type == "Message")
                {
                    // return our reply to the user
                    message.BotPerUserInConversationData = null;
                    return await Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new EchoDialog());
                }
            return null;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EchoDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Message> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;
            if (message.Text.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("echo request"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("echo reply");
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, it is very straight forward. When a user writes `echo request`, it returns `echo reply`. And that works. If a user doesn't write that, it should just ignore it, right? And it does ignore it for 99% of the words I say to it. But if I write the word `rus`, it just replies `rus.

I cannot possibly find out why it does that. I can't see anything wrong with the code, so can it be a but in the Bot Framework?

First I thought the problem was related to Slack, but after implementing FB Messenger to my bot I noticed it happens there too. Weirdly enough, it does not happen on the Bot Emulator on my PC, which makes me think it might not be code related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to fix the problem by turning off the translation service of the Bot Framework. I still have no idea why it returns those words though. I suspect it's a bug on their side